Nodemailer - Cannot send message - smtp connection socket is already destroyed
does anyone have experienced the error in the subject
If you please look into the following link for more details.
https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/10329
Not sure why is the smtp connection being destroyed if I'm using a singleton class.
Not sure what the proble is, the code looks good to me.
